# Mac mini 2012 mini-DisplayPort flashes to black intermittently with High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: display, high-sierra, mac-mini, displayport

I asked in the [apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8214721), but got no answer, so trying here...

Mac mini 2012 mini-displayport flashes to black intermittently with High Sierra 10.13.2

I'm setting up a new-to-me Mac Mini 2012 with a clean install from a bootable USB drive of High Sierra 10.13. It is connected to a LG 29UM67-P UltraWide display at 2560x1080 using a mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable. (Strangely, this display shows up as a 34" LG ULTRAWIDE Display according to the system)

After install, I'm on 10.13.1 and the display works normally.  However, once I updated to 10.13.2, the display became unstable––it flashes to black every 30 seconds. The problem is similar to the one described in this post:  Display flashes to solid black intermittently

I reinstalled 10.13.1 from the bootable USB drive and the problem persisted. It was an "upgrade" not a clean install because my user account was still there on reboot.

Then I erased the HD and repeated a clean install from the bootable USB drive to get back to 10.13.1––and now the display is rock steady.

what's happening and how can I fix this to get back to the latest version of OSX?

**UPDATE**

I have since discovered that the issue also appears on 10.13.1 when I wake from sleep. Oddly, if I plug in a second, mini-DP <-> HDMI cable and switch the monitor to an HDMI input, I get a stable display image at 1920x1080. After that, I can switch back to the mini-DP <-> DP cable and the display will again work on the DP input at 2560x1080.

Any ideas?